# Why are unassociated new users able to participate on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, meta, new-users

As per [participate in Meta privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/participate-in-meta) you do not require 5 reputation on Stack Overflow to participate on Meta Stack Overflow. I know the reason because Meta Stack Overflow is also Meta Stack Exchange. So users who don't have Stack Overflow account can also post here (e.g. discussion related to Stack Exchange).

But my concern is that why do we allow to post on Meta Stack Overflow who don't have any associate account(at least one)? For e.g. [this user*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/212716/the-welder) was able to ask an [off-topic programming question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168170/187824) without having any associate account.

IMHO to make a meaningful post on Meta, you should have a Stack Exchange account.

Is there any reason behind it?

<sub>* He just associated after asking that question</sub>

Comment: This question was downvoted by somebody because it argues that new users shouldn't be able to participate on MSO, unless I'm mistaken. I think it might be a result of an expectation that discussions should be asked neutrally, e.g. "might new users be too unfamiliar with MSO to produce quality questions?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> to make a meaningful post Meta, you should have a Stack Exchange account somewhere else

No. This site is also for total "strangers" to give feedback and report issues they might have seen as plain visitors, not as registered users. Not that we see it happening, but we should keep this door open.

I prefer to leave it like this and let people join at will; the off topic crap is cleaned quickly and efficiently, we have more than enough high rep users and mods roaming the place 24/7 to handle it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you ever seen it happen?

Comment: @Benjol good call, see my post now. ;)

Comment: On top of the "high" rep users those who are unable to close a question yet often help get stuff off the front page by downvoting off-topic questions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Fair enough. That makes sense. :)

Comment: Please tell me here if someone come from this door in future.

Comment: @hims056 sure thing, you'll be the first to know! (if I will remember ;))

Comment: @Benjol The more common case might be someone with account access issues who would have to sign up for a new account elsewhere before asking here. There's a better process for resolving those now, but not everyone is aware of it until they post here and get pointed in the right direction.